# Excel Array - Multiple Match Index - Not detecting one Criteria

Tags: arrays, excel

I have the below array to detect 3 different criteria and return multiple results from a data source with 10000 Rows.

```
{=IF(INDEX(Inventory!$A$3:$Q$10000;SMALL(IF(($C$4=Inventory!$A$3:$A$10000)*($C$3=Inventory!$E$3:$E$10000)*(Inventory!$F$3:$F$10000="NEW");ROW(Inventory!$A$3:$A$10000)-ROW($C$3)+2);ROW(Inventory!1:1));16)=0;"";INDEX(Inventory!$A$3:$Q$10000;SMALL(IF(($C$4=Inventory!$A$3:$A$10000)*($C$3=Inventory!$E$3:$E$10000)*(Inventory!$F$3:$F$10000="NEW");ROW(Inventory!$A$3:$A$10000)-ROW($C$3)+2);ROW(Inventory!1:1));16))}
```

The Inventory table goes like this

```
A                        |E       |F            |P
Standard Laptop          |Lisbon  |NEW          |XCVBMT
Engineering Laptop       |London  |DAMAGED      |CVFTYU
Multiple Vendor          |Madrid  |QUARANTINE   |CVBLPU
Standard Laptop          |Lisbon  |NEW          |JKHGLK
```

I Have A and E criteria to select from drop down lists in C3 and C4.

If I delete the below criteria from the array, it works:

```
($C$4=Inventory!$A$3:$A$10000)
```

I cleared all formats, changed rows, changed the criteria to D4 and tiped in manually, trimmed... I think is right in front of me but have no clue on whats wrong.

I hope this is enough information.

Thanks

Comment: It is really hard to tell as any test we do will work,  There is nothing apperently wrong with the formula,  Check and make sure that there is one line that satisfies all three conditions.  Then do a straight comparison: `=C4=Inventory!A150` if A150 had the cell that should be the same.  Do this with all three in that row and see if all three return TRUE.

Comment: All 3 come back true

Comment: In the test, `=(C4=Inventory!A3)*(C3=Inventory!E3)*("NEW"=Inventory!F3)` =1.   Same thing if I change to array. In the original array, the reply is #N/A.

Comment: If I reduce my table to 100 rows it works. Any ideas on how to make it calculate for the 10000?

Comment: Use a custom format to hide the `0` and only do the one index formula without the IF.  The two will always evaluate and it is killing your calcs.  Or, concatenate the criteria in a helper column and it will lessen the number of calcs needed.  Or look into vba doing an Advanced Filter.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for all the inputs, I knew it was right in front of me. Basically the #N/A's in the A Column where killing it. I created an iferror in A and voilá.